# Android Как закрыть приложение?

Tags: java, android

Как закрыть приложение и убрать его  из списка недавно использованных, **но оставить сервис**, который работает в фоновом режиме?

[image: Список недавно использованных приложений]
Рис 1. Список недавно использованных приложений

Пробовал использовать `finish()`, `finishAffinity()`, `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid())`, даже `System.exit(0)`.

Все они закрывают приложение, оставляют сервис, но из списка недавно использованных приложение никуда не уходит.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того чтобы убрать приложение из недавних можно использовать такой способ в `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true" ...
```

либо добавить флаг при старте:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS);
```

так же имеет смысл добавить в манифест эту строку:

```
android:noHistory= "true"
```

[Вот](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3762763/how-to-remove-application-from-recent-application-list) есть подобный вопрос

Comment: Спасибо, Вы очень помогли